# Stop gradient flickering in chrome and opera?

Tags: css, google-chrome, gradient, opera

I'm using a gradient for the background of my site. It looks fine in safari and firefox, but in chrome and opera there is serious flickering. I've read on other sites/posts about banding and dither issues with chrome. I have tried using CSS to render the gradient and also just an svg. Both of those have the same flickering result.

Is there a code I can write to force chrome and opera to render the gradient like safari or firefox?

I've tried  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); with and without the webkit prefix. It doesn't resolve the issue. Any other suggestions?

P.S. My gradient is 90 degrees (left to right) #66cccc to #349A9A. I don't know if the color makes any difference, but I'd be willing to adjust it *slightly* if that would resolve the issue.

Comment: what do you mean 'flickering' , exactly? Did you include all [vendor prefixes?](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) without a sample snippet, it's impossible to answer this definitely.

Comment: I did include all vendor prefixes, but that's besides the point because it happens even if I use an .svg. Unless I need to use prefixes on the .svg? I'm not sure how to do that, but if you think that's a solution, please tell me how to implement it. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to answer your first question. "Flickering" as in a rapid variable brightness, similar to a strobe light.

Comment: *please tell me how to implement it* What am I meant to advise you on? You've not included a sample, or a workable demo, or anything that could really help us to help you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known problem](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=226753) on with chrome on certain mac laptops.  It seems to be related to how their screens are built.  More information about how an LCD's construction can cause it to flicker under certain conditions is found in [this article](http://www.techmind.org/lcd/).

My experience with the issue seems to indicate that it seems to crop up with shades of gray.  Other colors don't seem to have issues.

Comment: Also happens on my Dell Windows 10 laptop.

Comment: I also have this problem on my Dell laptop with Dell Ultrasharp monitor

Answer (score -4):

i have the same problem. i've google it because it shows only in google chrome and found out that the problem is related with my macbook pro mid 2012 13" screen or intel hd4000 internal graphic card is causing damage (no one is sure who to blame)

Comment: To improve your answer, please use proper formatting/styling.  Also, any other details of how you resolved this problem would be very helpful.

Comment: i didn't resolve the problem cause it is hardware related. thank you for downvoting me ;) here is complete explanation for my problem: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=226753